# Algorithm which tells if a number is obtainable from a given set using only '+' ,'*' and brackets

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two list of numbers, for every member of the second one I must tell if it's obtainable using all the numbers of the first one and placing '+' or '*' and as many '(' ')' I want.
I can't change the order .

List1 can contain a max of 20 elements beetween 1 and 100.
List2 can contain max 5 elements beetween 1 and 20'000.

EX:

```
List1=[2 4 3 5]  
List2=[19 15 24]

19-> 2+(4*3)+5  YES   
15              NO
24->2*(4+3+5)   YES
```

With brute force it takes ages to handle inputs with List1 larger than 10.

edit: numbers are always positive.

edit:
I find the max and min numbers that are obtainable from the list and then I discard all the possibilities that have the  target outside this range, then I try all the remaining ones.

```
 MAX=n1*n2*n3*....*ni    if there are 1 thei r added to their smallest neighbour

 MIN=n1+n2+....+ni       1 excluded
```

Still it's not fast enough when input are big (List1 longer than 10 or numbers in List2 bigger than 10000)

Comment: Will your numbers always be positive?

Comment: I don't know if you'd find an easy to implement algorithm (if you found an algorithm at all) to do this, but you may be able to improve the efficiency of your brute force approach. Perhaps giving us a better idea about your current solution would help.

Comment: @user762836 from the last line of your question I infer that you already have some code. Then please let us have it. A piece of code is always great as a starting point.

Comment: Another thought - Is outputting more than YES or NO actually required? If you don't need to output -how- you use the numbers in the first list to get the relevant value from the second list, it's likely going to be much easier (and, hopefully, faster).

Comment: What class is this for?  For example, if you are currently studying dynamic programming, then you should use that for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

For each sublist of List1, compute the numbers between 1 and 20,000 that can be made with that sublist. The resulting DP bears resemblance to [CYK](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm).

I'm being somewhat vague here because this is almost certainly a programming contest problem.

Answer (score 3):

@u mad is correct, but I'll give a little more detail.

Suppose that `n = size of list 1`.  For each `0 <= i < j < n` you need to compute all of the distinct values in the range (1..20_000) that can be made from the numbers in the interval `[i, j-1]`.  You can do this with recursion and memoization.

Once you've done this then the problem is easy.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It was stated as a requirement that the order of the numbers has to match the input order.  Thus `(1+5)*(3+7)` is not valid.  If you allow the order of numbers to change, the problem becomes significantly more difficult.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't read the question closely enough! Will delete that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a smart brute force which discards sets of equations by chunks.